# .htaccess RewriteRule to preserve url parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have some trouble with the `.htaccess` to convert the parameters into a normal url.

For `domain.com/artikel.php?url=title`, I want to visit it with `domain.com/artikel/title`.

My htaccess rewrite is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artikel/([^/]*)$ /artikel.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "give it back"?

Comment: And what is your actual issue?

Comment: I want to change the URL from domain.com/artikel.php?url=title to domain.com/artikel/title. But when i try the .htaccess it responds with a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: A http status 500 is an "internal http server error". So that means you need to dig deeper to find the actual cause of that generic error message (it is generic since it is targeted towards visitors of your service). Specifically you need to monitor your http servers error log file (you cannot operate a http server without doing that anyway). Here you will read the actual issue, I dare say the issue probably is that you have not loaded the http servers rewriting module which means the ``Rewrite...`` commands are unknown.